# How to get the child count for parent child relationship

Tags: mysql, database

Using this query will get the result as in shown in below image link

```
select c.property_title,b.property_title as building,d.property_title as floor,e.house_name as house,
    f.room_no as room,g.bed_no as bed
    from g_property_group c
    left join g_property_group b on b.parent_id = c.id and b.is_deleted = '0'
    left join g_property_group d on d.parent_id = b.id and d.is_deleted = '0'
    left join g_house e on e.property_group_id = d.id and e.is_deleted = '0'
    left join g_room f on f.house_id = e.id and f.is_deleted = '0'
    left join g_bed g on  g.room_id = f.id and g.is_deleted = '0'
    where c.id = 'a976df373f75d3f8cc49938ae9fead8e4fc8ad19'
    and c.is_deleted = '0'
```

[image: Click here to view image]

[image: Click here to see hierarchy]

I have written the query for fetching the count of parent and child .will get the building count as 7 floor count as 7 house count as 5 room count as 4, instead the count of building should be 2, floor = 2, house = 4, Rooms = 5 and Bed 1.

```
select c.property_title,count(b.property_title)as building,count(d.property_title)as floor,count(e.house_name)as house,
count(f.room_no)as room,count(g.bed_no) as bed
from g_property_group c
left join g_property_group b on b.parent_id = c.id and b.is_deleted = '0'
left join g_property_group d on d.parent_id = b.id and d.is_deleted = '0'
left join g_house e on e.property_group_id = d.id and e.is_deleted = '0'
left join g_room f on f.house_id = e.id and f.is_deleted = '0'
left join g_bed g on g.house_id = g.id and g.room_id = f.id and g.is_deleted = '0'
where c.id = 'a976df373f75d3f8cc49938ae9fead8e4fc8ad19'
and c.is_deleted = '0'
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Add what's your expected result and your table structure.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rdFIU.png this is  actual table structure we get from the above query. and from that the count of building should be 2 and the count of floor column should be 2 and the count of house  should be 4 and the count of room should be 5 and the count of bed should be 1....

Comment: but if i give the count(b.property_title) then its giving as 7 which should be 2..

Comment: Can I know why house should be 4 and room should be 5??

Comment: click this link to know the hierarchy http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ypi9F.png

Comment: I have added a query, check and let me know if it gives any problem.

Comment: I don't see your group by clause. Maybe this will help you: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ scroll down to the headline AGGREGATE FUNCTIONS IN A NESTED SET. There your problem is resolved and explained. I couldn't do it better so I'm referring to that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**SQL SERVER**

```
select count([building]) over (order by building) as [bulding count],
       count([floor]) over (order by [floor],[building]) as [floor count],
       count([house]) over (order by building,[floor],[house]) as [house count],
       count([room]) over (order by building,[floor],[house],[room]) as [room count],
       count([bed]) over (order by building,[floor],[house],[room],[bed]) as [room count]
```

Comment: mysql does not support over() function

Comment: Siraj M, You are using mysql?

Comment: @SirajM, You had added SQL-server tag, which creates a confusion.

Comment: @SirajM, So, I think this answer is nor more relevant.